# The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory.

Tags: asp.net

I'm building an SMS application and get an error. I don't understand the error because I'm a beginner.

The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. Here it's showing as sql server express but I want to use sql server 2008 DB.

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5066458
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity) +341
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +129
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout) +270
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>   +195    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +232
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection) +5080107
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +31
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +76
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server,
>   String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString) +82
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server
>   database.]
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server,
>   String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString) +137
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String
>   server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures
>   features, Boolean install) +94
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String
>   dbFileName, String connectionString) +27
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
>   fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +395

Comment: What is the connection string?  You say you want to use SQL Server 2008, but according to the error the connection string is for a local SQL Server Express file.  The stack trace indicates that it's just failing to connect to any database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your connection string to your web.config file? If you have, what does it look like? 
Sorry I can't add comments due to not having enough points.

Comment: i've even added the connection string,it looks like as below....    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=192.168.7.30\INST2008;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />